# Menu Child items should be displayed on all pages in ImpressPages

Tags: php, impresspages

I want to show only childs pages in all pages

```
$pages = \Ip\Menu\Helper::getChildItems();
          echo ipSlot('menu', $pages);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child items work for a selected page. You should define a parent.

Here's a definition of this function:

```
public static function getChildItems($pageId = null, $depthLimit = 1000, $orderBy = null) { ... }
```

If you don't provide any parameters, current page is taken as a parent and all its children are returned. This means each page will show a different menu.

Therefore, provide a specific `pageId` to this function to make menu the same on all pages.

P.S. if you have some specific case, define it. Maybe it can be solved with different tools.